# Messed up grub boot order

Tags: grub2, uefi, bootloader

While I was messing around with my boot order I moved efi firmware to the top and restarted my machine. Now I am stuck in a loop of uefi and boot orders trying to get back to my desktop. How do I fix this.

Comment: Is it efiboot menu order or grub menu order. If grub menu, you should be able to press escape (perhaps multiple times) during or just after UEFI/CSM/BIOS screen at initial start up of system.

Comment: Oldfred makes a good point I hadn't considered. If it's GRUB boot order, my answer below will be inapplicable.

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed the problem. To think that it was so easy makes me feel kind of dumb. Having ubuntu has been a great learning experience for me and when these problems come up I learn even more. If you don't mind though. Can you tell me what I did. Just so I can remember it and use it as I learn more.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to launch Ubuntu from a live usb, download boot-repair and let it reinstall grub.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this except as a last resort. The reason is that Boot Repair does a *lot* more than fix the immediate problem. In doing so much more, that creates the opportunity to create *new* problems. To be sure, it's far from certain that you'll create new problems by using Boot Repair in this way; but it's sort of like using a huge sledgehammer to nail a tiny 1/2-inch nail into a bird house. It'll do the job, but it might just damage the bird house in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Boot to Ubuntu and use `efibootmgr`:

1. Open a Terminal.
2. Type `sudo efibootmgr` to see your boot order (or `sudo efibootmgr -v` to see more detail).
3. Note the `BootOrder` line and the `Boot####` numbers for all the entries on that line and for the `ubuntu` entry. Note that the numbers are in hexadecimal.
4. Determine the boot order you want. `ubuntu` should be first, possibly followed by Windows and other things.
5. Use the `-o` option to `efibootmgr` to set that boot order, as in `sudo efibootmgr -o 5,3,D,2001` to set the boot order to `Boot0005` first, `Boot0003` second, and so on.